# Why was the question about vending machines closed?

Tags: support

While using technical terms and poorly written, the [question about vending machines](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/12052/1873) actually asks for a device recommendation (although OP couldn't find it). Or at least can be solved using a device recommendation. And the device in question does not break rules I'm aware of.

If you don't know that MDB means Multi-Drop Bus (already suggested an edit) then this question does indeed make little sense.

Edit: I asked this question in part to flag it, in part because it shows that what might be a regular question for one person can be impossible to understand for another. Even within our rules.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to just ask a direct question about obscure devices, only referring that vending machine question

Answer (score 1):

What was unclear in that question was not "MDB" (although clarifying that does help it to make more sense); what's unclear is actually what the OP is trying to do. The phrase "connect a vending machine to an android operating system" makes little sense; it's not the operating system you'd be connecting it to. While the OS may handle the connection itself, that's no use without having some other software or hardware that makes use of that connection. Clarification of what the intent is and what that other hardware or software might be would help make this question clearer.

Comment: For me the intent was quite clear: build a vending machine with an Android tablet as the interface (instead of, say, buttons). But I work designing hardware so maybe I read it between the lines since I have an idea about the architecture of vending machines.

Comment: I could probably suggest a more comprehensive edit based on my guess of OPs intent but a) IIRC it was an unnamed user with 1 rep and b) I would have to be at my PC, which will be tomorrow